# Selecting first elements of a class children of elements of another class in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors

I want to select first elements of a class which are children of elements of another class using jQuery. Please have a look at an example below to understand my question.

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="b">Select this</div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="b">Select this</div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">Select this</div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

I want to write a code in jQuery which will select all first elements of class b under all elements of class a.

If I use the following code in jQuery, it does not work:

```
$(".a div.b:first-child").html('Changed!!!!');​
```

How can I select those divs, which I marked as "Select this" in the html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:first` instead of `:first-child` and Also use `.find` for specific sections. See below,

```
$(".a").find("div.b:first").html('Changed!!!!');
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kjV5j/1/

Comment: > Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method.

Comment: @MaratTanalin `first-child` represents any element that is the first child element of its parent. I don't think it can be used in this case.

Comment: This case is perfectly addressed via _two_ selectors as in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13349667/1211187).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.a > .b:first-child, .a > :not(.b) + .b
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K9p9e/)

Compared with nonstandard `:first` pseudoclass supported by jQuery, this should work much *faster* in browsers that support `querySelectorAll()` natively (IE9+).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
    $(".a div.b:eq(0)").html('Changed!!!!'); 
    // OR
    $(".a div.b:first").html('Changed!!!!');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the text in the tags that have 'Select this':

```
$('.a div').each(function()
{
  if ( $(this).html() == 'Select this' )
    $(this).html('changed');
});
```

Comment: The elements won't always have "Select This", he's just using that as an example.